# F# negative indices in array

Tags: arrays, dictionary, f#

In my application there is a need to precompute and keep trigonometric function values for some particular angle parameters, the range varies from -90 to 180 degree.
I can create arrays(one for each sine, cos etc) which will store value for -90 angle on 0th index and while retrieving I can subtract 90 from the index.

but is there any other way in F# to specify range of index, if we want to use [-90 .. 180]
so that I can have more meaningful implementation.

considering alternate solution, will usage of dictionary be as fast as usage of simple 2D arrays.

Comment: You problem is to define a range from -90 to 180 or extracting by key like `let value = precomputed.[-90]`

Comment: yes i want to extract precomputed values for given angle. let value = precomputed.[-90]

Comment: Normally, [indexed properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233202.aspx) (including `Item`) can be used to create custom indexers. But I'm not sure about their overhead if the program is *this* tightly performance-limited. Are you *sure* the standard trigonometric functions are a performance bottleneck? Is speed really the problem here? Are you running on hardware where these functions are slow?

Comment: I am dealing with a huge scale problem where i would like to avoid any kind of processing delay, because of stringent performance requirement, thats why i dont want to compute the values at run time rather keeping them stored in an array where retrieval will be really fast.

Comment: I really doubt that storing a sin table will be faster than calculating - you are taking a pretty serious cache hit for a calculation is pretty fast

Comment: @John Palmer It does in fact help; see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand well your problem you would need to retrieve precomputed values by the key/index which is a given angle going from -90 to 180. Something like this ?

```
let value = precomputed.[-90]
```

You could use `Map` for that. F# maps are implemented as immutable AVL trees, an efficient data structure which forms a self-balancing binary tree. This can be very efficient if you have a precomputed data and you need to look up by key fre­quently. Its immutabil­ity in this case ensures that the sta­tic data can­not be mod­i­fied by mis­take and has lit­tle impact to per­for­mance as you never need to mutate it once initialized. However if you need to modify it frequently I would advice you to use a regular .NET Dictionary because they are based on hashtable which has a better performance than AVL trees.

You could turn the list into the map where the key would be the angle and the value would be the precomputed one :

```
let precomputedValus f =
    [for i in -90..180 ->
            i, f(i)]
            |> Map.ofList
```

Where `f` is the function doing the precomputation. So you obtain your precomputed map for every angle something like that.

```
let sinValues = precomputedValus (fun e -> sin (float e))
```

And you can access the procomputed sin value like that

```
> sinValues.[-90];;
val it : float = -0.8939966636
```

Comment: values are immutable so i think dictionary is not required. I find out the solution given by you quite suitable thankx for that.....now i think with this i can compare performance and draw some conclusions.

Comment: Yes, map will fit greatly

Comment: The question asks for input in degrees; `sin` takes radian input. Also, please note that this is slower than direct computation by a factor on typical x86 machines and uses. (I just did a rough test-run, and the precomputation caused a major slowdown to less than 40% of original speed. Of course, this may depend on hardware, caching, branch prediction due to order of inputs, etc.)

Comment: you can use whatever function you need instead of sin. It's just a sample

Comment: that degree to radian conversion already taken care of.. .. you mean to say lookup will be costlier than computation for x86?

Comment: @user3742344 You will need to profile in the actual usage scenario to be sure. I just want to warn that performance optimization is not simple. Speed of binary trees heavily depends on branch prediction, i.e. order of inputs. Lookup tables use cache, which can slow down the rest of the program. Another option to consider: when precomputing arbitrary functions, the `dict` operator for immutable lookup tables can be much faster than maps. Trigonometric functions are usually subject to hardware features and compiler optimization, so it's an extreme case I wouldn't normally try to optimize.

Comment: @Vandroiy What is slower? Precomputation or lookup? Also, I don't get the same results as you do. Remember that precomputing happens only once and lookups should be faster that computing the value on every access. Anyway some profiling should be done in a real scenario to be sure.

Comment: In my test, precomputation was much worse in a scenario that seems optimal for it: highly dependent calculations prevent CPU-parallelism for direct computation, no other things using cache, inputs ordered for nice branch prediction on tree traversal. I basically looped through 1..180 for a total of 10M calls, adding the results. (Single thread on an AMD Bulldozer processor.) But yes, in the end, this can only be properly profiled in the actual application, in the real context it will be used in.

Comment: @anushri if the performance is so tight, that you want to cache trigonometric functions, you'll most likely only ever see a speed up, if you go for manual index calculation on an array. A dictionary still has a non-trivial lookup cost and trigonometric functions are very, very fast. That said, a pre-computed array with manual indexing might be a little faster.

Comment: The performance optimization should be definietly checked while profiling the app in the real world scenario. This depends on how costly the actual calculating function is. Question mentioned rather an idiomatic take on the problem than the performance one but this should not be omitted.

Answer (score 1):

A little index arithmetic will be of use:

```
let inline idx i = (i + 270) % 270
```

since it's `inline` the overhead is going to be very, very small. And you can just use `myArray.[idx -90]`. (you might have to write different modulo values, but you get the picture)

Comment: Note that this will fail on inputs smaller than -270 with the default `%` operator. (Which might or might not be okay for a given use case)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to simply make some function which given some `i` returns a pre-computed value of `sin i`:

```
let array_table = 
  let a = Array.init 271 (fun i -> sin <| float (i-90))
  fun i -> a.[i+90]
```

To lookup the sine of, say, 42, you simply do `table 42`.

anushri and Tomasz both mention using Maps instead of Arrays, but in my experience, these are not good candidates for storing precomputed values, as they are *much* slower than Arrays. Let's try:

```
let map_table = 
  let m = Seq.init 271 (fun i -> i-90, sin <| float i) |> Map.ofSeq
  fun i -> Map.find i m 

let no_table = 
  fun i -> sin (float i)

// Benchmarking code omitted (100000 lookups of each value in -90..270)
```

When I run this, `array_table` is roughly 8 times faster than `no_table` and 22 times faster than `map_table`:

```
> fsharpi --optimize+ memo.fsx 
map_table
Real: 00:00:02.922, CPU: 00:00:02.924, GC gen0: 4, gen1: 0
no_table
Real: 00:00:01.091, CPU: 00:00:01.091, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 0
array_table
Real: 00:00:00.130, CPU: 00:00:00.130, GC gen0: 3, gen1: 0
```